# How to "Compile on save" in netbeans after I change the build directory?

Tags: java, netbeans

My NetBeans' "Compile on save" feature works well.

But after I change my project's build directory by adding a line

```
build.dir=path/to/my/own/build/dir
```

or

```
build.classes.dir=path_to_my_own_build_dir/classes
```

to the file `path_to_my_project/nbproject/private/private.properties`, NetBeans doesn't "Compile on save" anymore.

I must click the "Compile" or "Clean and Compile" button to compile my project.

I checked that in `nbproject/private/private.properties`: there is a `compile.on.save=true` line, and the "Compile on save" checkbox in my project's property dialog is checked.

Is there any way to let NetBeans "Compile on save"?